# Permissions error with gem install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, permissions, rubygems

I had a very weird problem yesterday, where in the middle of trying to figure out some heroku problems, my whole Rails environment just disappeared. Bundle, RVM, rails, etc were no longer recognized. So I just ignored the possible cause and reinstalled everything. Mostly worked, but now I'm running into permissions problems. If I bundle install, it needs me to input my computer password for permission.

And I just ran into the following problem trying to "gem install heroku" in a new directory I wanted to deploy.

ERROR: While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError) You don't have write permissions into the /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8 directory.

Any idea how I get those permissions back so things run smoothly again?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use chmod on the directory something like this:

sudo chmod -R  g+w /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8

That might work.

Comment: Thanks. Just tried it, but it comes up with the same error. "sudo gem install heroku" just did it, but shouldn't that have been unnecessary after the chmod? Or do I just have to restart my terminal or something? (Sorry, still pretty new to this).

Comment: Restarted, and it has the same problem.

Comment: looking at the gem folder, you are not using rvm at all(but you mentioned you used rvm before the rails env messed up?). If you still have rvm, try `source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm` to reload the config

Comment: Whoa! That fixed it. Don't know why. I thought I'd reinstalled RVM. Super confused by what's going on, but I'll try to look into it. Thanks for the help, everyone!